# Spring Boot : Error :Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error .
**Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed**
Can someone help me figure out why?.

```
    @Entity
    public class Product {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @OneToOne(
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL
        )
        @JoinColumn(name = "details_id")
        private Details details;
//Getters and setters left out for brevity
    }


@Entity
public class Details {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private float price;
    private float discount;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "details")
    private Product product;
}


@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping("/getAllProducts")
    public Iterable<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }
}

   @RestController
public class DetialsController {
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    DetailsRepository detailsRepository;

    @PostMapping("/details")
    public Details addDetails(@RequestBody Details details) {
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.setDetails(details);
        productRepository.save(newProduct);
        return detailsRepository.save(details);
    }
}
```

I am able to make the POST call to /details; for adding details successfully. But when i make GET call to /getAllProducts, I am getting this error 
**Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an issue with bidirectional relationships, as they hold references to each other, at deserialization, Jackson runs in an infinite loop. My first suggestion would be adding `@JsonIgnore` to one end of the relation.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "details")
@JsonIgnore
private Product product;
```

Afterward, if that solved your issue, you can look over @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference and @JsonIdentityInfo.

You can also look over this [link](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/bidirectional-relationship-in-json) for more insight

Comment: On adding @JsonIgnore , i am getting this error No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.post.postComment.Model.Product["details"]->com.example.post.postComment.Model.Details_$$_jvst4cd_1["handler"])

Comment: Can you try removing the lazy fetching type?

Comment: That is one great article.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
    @Entity
    public class Product {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;


        @JsonBackReference(value = "details_id")
        @OneToOne(
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL
        )
        @JoinColumn(name = "details_id")
        private Details details;
//Getters and setters left out for brevity
    }


@Entity
public class Details {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private float price;
    private float discount;

    @JsonManagedReference(value = "details")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "details",,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;
}
```